# Issue while refreshing token - OIDC - "Error refreshing token Wrong issuer"

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

I am using Azure + Angular + Java to validate the token.

**Angular (UI):**

angular-oauth2-oidc library

**Provided information :**

```
      issuer: this.configData.issuer,
      clientId: "",
      redirectUri: "",
      tokenEndpoint: "",
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "",
      loginUrl: "",
      logoutUrl: "",
      showDebugInformation: environment.env === 'local',
      disablePKCE: true
```

**Java part :**

For the access token , the information is passed like

```
grant_type=%s&code=%s&redirect_uri=%s&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s
```

The refresh token is sent in the response for the above call.

After some time , the refresh_token is called with

```
grant_type=%s&client_id=%s&refresh_token=%s&client_secret=%s
```

For the refresh call ,  there is an exception :
"Error refreshing token Wrong issuer"

During the exploration , there is a suggestion to add skipIssuerCheck: true in the idms authentication part in UI.
This introduces other issue of **Error refreshing token Error: Parameter jwks expected!**

During the search , got the suggestion to add the following information in UI. Not sure about the information/data to be passed for each field here.

```
this.oauthService.jwks = {
 keys: [
     {
        kid: "X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk",
        nbf: 1493763266,
        use: "sig",
        kty: "RSA",
        e: "AQAB",
        n: "tVKUtcx_n9rt5afY_2WFNvU6PlFMggCatsZ3l4RjKxH0jgdLq6CScb0P3ZGXYbPzXvmmLiWZizpb-h0qup5jznOvOr-Dhw9908584BSgC83YacjWNqEK3urxhyE2jWjwRm2N95WGgb5mzE5XmZIvkvyXnn7X8dvgFPF5QwIngGsDG8LyHuJWlaDhr_EPLMW4wHvH0zZCuRMARIJmmqiMy3VD4ftq4nS5s8vJL0pVSrkuNojtokp84AtkADCDU_BUhrc2sIgfnvZ03koCQRoZmWiHu86SuJZYkDFstVTVSR0hiXudFlfQ2rOhPlpObmku68lXw-7V-P7jwrQRFfQVXw"}
]}
```

Any help here to solve the issue of the error "Error refreshing token Wrong issuer".

Answer (score 0):

this.oauthService.jwks information is provided by the identity server.

For the fix of ""Error refreshing token Wrong issuer" ,

1. The field skipIssuerCheck: true is added
2. The jwks information is received from Identity Server and the information has also been added in the oAuth configuration file.

Note: Any call `this.oAuthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();` should be commented out.